# REGEXP_SUBSTR Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract a substring from a text string in postgresql. The column name of the text string is short_description and I am using the REGEXP_SUBSTR function to define a regex that will return only the portion that I want:

```
SELECT  short_description, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(short_description,'\\[[^=[]*') AS space
FROM my_table
```

This returns the following:

```
short_description                                        space
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG] ACB DEF [HIJ]           |            [ABC12]
```

What I would like to pull is the following:

```
short_description                                        space
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG] ACB DEF [HIJ]           |            [ABCDEFG]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Regex character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) to help with this kind of match. Here I'm looking for letters only, surrounded by brackets, and a following space. Note the use of double backslash `\\` to escape the literal brackets and the double brackets `[[:a:]]` for the character class

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG] ACB DEF [HIJ]','\\[[[:alpha:]]+\\] ');
 regexp_substr
---------------
 [ABCDEFG]
```

You could also use the SPLIT_PART function achieve something similar by splitting on a closing bracket `]` and choosing the 3rd value.

```
SELECT SPLIT_PART('[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG] ACB DEF [HIJ]',']',3);
 split_part
------------
 [ABCDEFG
```

I recommend using the built in functions rather than a UDF if at all possible. UDFs are fantastic when you need them but they do incur a performance penalty.

Comment: not sure about performance but yes absolutely use this rather than my UDF version! - good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.
I have found the right regexp expression using 
[https://txt2re.com](https://txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG]%20ACB%20DEF%20[HIJ]%20&1)

Then, I have implemented it as a python redshift UDF

```
create or replace function f_regex (input_str varchar(max),regex_expression varchar(max))
  returns VARCHAR(max)
stable
as $$
import re
rg = re.compile(regex_expression,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
return rg.search(input_str).group(1)
$$ language plpythonu;

select f_regex('[ABC12][1][ABCDEFG] ACB DEF [HIJ] '::text,'.*?\\[.*?\\].*?\\[.*?\\](\\[.*?\\])'::text);
```

Once you have created the function, you can use it within any of your redshift selects.

So, in your case:

```
SELECT  short_description, 
f_regex(short_description::text,'.*?\\[.*?\\].*?\\[.*?\\](\\[.*?\\])'::text) AS space
FROM my_table
```